# GUI bug in JDialog box?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, joptionpane, jdialog

Currently making a DnD utility that calls a window to roll dice in. When you close the window and reopen it, a lot of the user interface is moved around and non functional. Where did I go wrong?

[correct box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMQJm.jpg)

[image: correct box]

[bugged box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVpj7.jpg)

[image: bugged box]
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
mntmDiceRoller.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            DisplayRollPanel();
        }

        private void DisplayRollPanel() {
            Delta.rollPane.main(null);

        }
    });
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        rollPane dialog = new rollPane();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public rollPane() {
    setResizable(false);
    setName("DiceRollerDialog");
    setType(Type.POPUP);
    setTitle("Dice Roller");
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 350);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][grow][][grow][][19.00,grow][][grow][][][][grow][][]", "[][][][][][][][][][][]"));
```

/////////////rest of the code omitted/////////////////////////////////

Comment: You might consider reading about naming conventions in java. Java Classes should start with an uppercase letter.  It might not be a problem for you personally now, but the bigger your code gets and the more people are included, the more annoying it will become and unnecessarily make your code harder to read as everybody expects a method or variable name and then reads "new rollPane()". In your case: "rollPane" should be "RollPane". Just a general hint for you ;)

Comment: I had only been taught camelCase so far, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: Don't invoke the main() method directly. That method is meant to be invoked when you start the JVM. No need to set the dialog type as "POPUP". Not sure what that does but I have never used it before. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: that's the thing, I don't know how else to call the RollPane. calling main() directly was the first thing that worked, and I didn't know what else to try.

I'll post an MCV once I find another way to call RollPane.

Comment: It seems that you are adding the first row of components twice to your GUI. Check the methods that create the dialog window (Constructor) and the methods that show the window (ones that contain `dialog.setVisible(true);`) I am assuming that you are calling one of the GUI building methods before calling `dialog.setVisible(true);` on allready constructed GUI. But that is only a guess and you should work on posting the MCVE.